# multi-faceted heat map with ggplot for selected portion of X with additional text labels on it

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I have the following data:

```
Id = paste ("ID-", 1:5, sep = "")
position <- rep(seq (1, 100,10), each = 5)
group = rep (rep(rep (1:5, each = length (Id)), each = length(position)))
yvar <- rnorm (length(position), 0.5, 0.1)
ycat <- c(sample (c("A", "B"), length(yvar), replace = TRUE))
namevar <- rep(Id, length(group)/length(Id))
mydf <- data.frame (namevar, group, position, yvar, ycat)
```

`group` is a faceting variable, `position` is a continous x variable. `yvar` is used for filling the color of the tiles. `ycat` is a text label for each tile. I want to create a plot with empty space for all values, except certain tiles that I select to plot with a fill color and labels.

Here is what I have so far:

```
  ggplot(mydf,aes(y=Id,x=position)) +
      facet_wrap(~group) +     
      geom_tile(aes(fill = yvar),colour = "black") +
      geom_text(aes(label = ycat)) +
      labs(x = NULL,y = NULL)
```

[image]

I'd like the plot to look like this except have blank space everywhere except, for instance, group 1 between 30-50 and group 5 between 20-60, sort of like this:

[image]

Comment: Is your question how to remove the x and y axis labels on the last plot? i.e. how to remove the 0, 20, 40, etc on the x axis and how to remove the ID-1, ID-2 on the y axis?

Comment: My question now is just to shade selected regions, for example positions in group 1 - x value from 30 to 50  and group 5 - x value from 20 to 60, rest would be while but still present.

Comment: So you want to plot all the values, you simply want to change which tiles are shaded?

Comment: @joran see the edits, to display values between my defined positions and get rid of cell outlines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will produce your last plot, but only shade selected regions:

```
ggplot(mydf,aes(y=Id,x=position)) +
  facet_wrap(~group) + 
  geom_blank() +    
  geom_tile(data = subset(mydf,(group == 1 & position >= 30 & position <= 50) | 
                                (group == 5 & position >= 20 & position <= 60)),aes(fill = yvar),colour = "black") +
  geom_text(data = subset(mydf,(group == 1 & position >= 30 & position <= 50) | 
                                (group == 5 & position >= 20 & position <= 60)),aes(label = ycat),size = 3) +
  labs(x = NULL,y = NULL)
```

Comment: thanks, it is interesting that you are selecting group 1,5, but when I plot the  1,2 is getting plotting  !

Comment: Even I select, 1,3 or 1,2 - always plots in 1, 2 facets